# How do I create a function which copies and inserts it's own div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-4

**Edit**: Visit https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/40740/ for the final solution!

**Update**: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634805/bootstrap-forms-how-to-dynamically-create-unique-names-for-radio-buttons) is a followup!

I have a div with an "add question" (Bootstrap) radio button. My intention is, that the div in which the button is placed should be copied and placed underneath when the mentioned button is clicked:

[image: "singleQuestionModule"]

How do I do that? Nothing happens when I click the button.

[js.fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/svo70pdt/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="singleQuestionModule">
    <div class="question-wrapper">
        <form class="form-group">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <fieldset class="form-group row">
                    <legend class="col-form-legend col-sm-10"></legend>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="input-group input-group">
                            <label id="wQuestionLabel" class="form-control-label" style="width: 540px;" for="wQuestion">Question:</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="input-group input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="" id="wQuestion" style="width: 540px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="input-group input-group">
                            <label id="questionOptions" class="form-control-label" style="width: 540px;"
                                   for="wQuestion">Enter
                                avaible options:</label>
                        </div>                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

                            <label class="btn btn-success">
                                <input type="radio" name="options" id="radioAddQuestion"
                                       onclick="addQuestionModule('singleQuestionModule')"
                                       autocomplete="off">Add Question</label>

                            <label class="btn btn-success">
                                <input type="radio" name="options" id="radioSaveTest" value="saveTest()"
                                       autocomplete="off">Save Test </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#radioAddQuestion").click(function() {
    var html = $("#" + singleQuestionModule).html();
    $(html).insertAfter("#" + singleQuestionModule);
});
```

[This is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/fc2n92co/13/) (not my code) that I tried to reproduce.

Comment: Your problem is, that you use radio inputs instead of normal buttons. Radio Inputs doesn't support `.click()` function

Comment: Why are you using radio as button? Just use `<button>`... And rour demo is incomplete.. Nothing happens because you did not include the jquery source file

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about what you want to do but the idea is to create a custom test so you need to add question and then at the end "save" the test, right? You should put your 2 buttons out of the div and only add question, if each bloc have a "add question" and "save test" button it's  strange, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/DTcHh/40709/)**.

Your code will work if you define `singleQuestionModule` and remove the inline-event.

**NOTE :** If you want the radio button click event to be attached to the new created questions you need to use event delegation `.on()` like :

```
$("body").on("click", "#radioAddQuestion", function() {
```

Code:

```js
$("body").on('click', '#radioAddQuestion', function() {
  var singleQuestionModule = "singleQuestionModule";
  var question = $(".question:first").html();
  var question_label = $(".question-label:first").html();

  $(question_label).insertBefore(".options-label");
  $(question).insertBefore(".options-label");
});
```

```css
#singleQuestionModule {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="singleQuestionModule">
  <div class="question-wrapper">
    <form class="form-group">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <fieldset class="form-group row">
          <legend class="col-form-legend col-sm-10"></legend>
          <div class="form-group row question-label">
            <div class="input-group input-group">
              <label id="wQuestionLabel" class="form-control-label" style="width: 540px;" for="wQuestion">Question:</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row question">
            <div class="input-group input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="" id="wQuestion" style="width: 540px;">
            </div>
          </div>
          <span class="options-label"></span>
          <br>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="input-group input-group">
              <label id="questionOptions" class="form-control-label" style="width: 540px;" for="wQuestion">Enter avaible options:</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

              <label class="btn btn-success" id="radioAddQuestion">
                <input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off">Add Question</label>

              <label class="btn btn-success">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="radioSaveTest" value="saveTest()" autocomplete="off">Save Test </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I test your JSFiddle it only add a bloc when you click on the first bloc, is it normal? I think to keep the use "logic" the two button should be "delete" in other bloc and only present in the last one, no? But at least you anwser his question and you add new bloc so it's cool ^^

Comment: Thanks for your intervention @MickaelLeger ... Check the note in my post.. I'm working on update.

Comment: I tried to change your Fiddle and if you just put the "form-group row" div out of the main div it still works but look more "logical" ! But maybe I didn't understand the point of OP with this code :)

Comment: Check this one after update https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/DTcHh/40709/

Comment: It look better for me, but can't talk for OP ! :)

Comment: Hello guys! Sorry for the delay. Been a quite eventful day. I will have time to try your suggestions when I am home... Thank you for all your efforts.

Comment: It's better that the save test is at the last row! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: The whole div should be repeated. In the div, a teacher wil be able to write a question and four alternatives for the students. But I think that same code as in the suggestions is possible to use with a slight modification, since I only want the buttons to appear after the last question. The idea is that the whole test, with questions and alternatives is created right there. The intention with the radio buttons in front of the div is to indicate the alternative that is the right answer!

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I did continue with the project today! And I have quite happy with the result: [https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/40740/](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/40740/)