# Bootstrap forms: How to dynamically create unique names for radio buttons

Tags: jquery, vue.js, bootstrap-4

This question is a follow-up to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47902408/how-do-i-create-a-function-which-copies-and-inserts-its-own-div).

This [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MyRgF/) exemplifies what I want to achieve.

**Final [Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/60627/) provided by @Scaramouche**

The function below is dynamically building up a "list" with radio buttons in groups of four.

Each of these group should have a unique name, which makes it possible to choose one of the options while still making it possible to choose other options in the other "groups". What makes this a challenge is that this "list" is built with Bootstrap forms. How do I do, to create these names dynamically? This can be done either with Vue or with JavaScript (no preference there).

**HTML**  on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/59942/)

```
<div id="singleQuestionModule">
    <form class="form-group">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <fieldset class="form-group row">
                <span class="module">
                    <legend class="col-form-legend col-sm-10"></legend>
                    <div class="input-group input-group">
                        <label id="wQuestionLabel" class="form-control-label" style="width: 540px;" for="wQuestion">Question:</label>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="input-group input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="" id="wQuestion" style="width: 540px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="input-group input-group">
                            <label id="questionOptions" class="form-control-label" style="width: 540px;"
                                   for="wQuestion">Enter
                                avaible options:</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="input-group input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <input type="radio" name= "q" id="option1" aria-label="">
                  </span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="" style="width: 540px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="input-group input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <input type="radio" name="q" id="option2" aria-label="">
                  </span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="" style="width: 540px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="input-group input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <input type="radio" name="q" id="option3" aria-label="">
                  </span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="" style="width: 540px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="input-group input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <input type="radio" name="q" id="option4" aria-label="">
                  </span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="" style="width: 540px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </span>
                <span class="options-label"></span>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-success" id="radioAddQuestion">
                            <input type="radio" @click="counter += 1" name="options" autocomplete="off">Add Question</label>

                        <label class="btn btn-success">
                            <input type="radio" name="options" id="radioSaveTest" value="saveTest()" autocomplete="off">Save
                            Test </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("body").on('click', '#radioAddQuestion', function () {

    let singleQuestionModule = "singleQuestionModule";
    let question = $(".module:first").html();
    let question_label = $(".question-label:first").html();

    $(question_label).insertBefore(".options-label");
    $(question).insertBefore(".options-label");

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a counter to modify the name for the next group. Also changed `.html()` to `.clone()` to work with a copy of the whole element instead of just its content.

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/60016/

Comment: Very neat and understandable solution!

Comment: Now the new divs are coming first, and they are pushing the others down.  I would like to have the cloned div after the last one, so the first question is on top! How do I do that?

Comment: @josefdev did u change something? in https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/60016/ every time a `span.module` is added, it's added at the end, right before `options-label`. what I noticed, which might be what's tricking you, is that being a clone of the first, it appears with the same data as the first, which might cause the impression of it BEING the first, but it's not, they are all being added at the end. try changing the content of the inputs and the radios of each new one after adding another and you'll see what I mean. you could solve this by *cleaning* all inputs every time a new `span` is added

Comment: @Scaramouce Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to look for the last `.module` added. Now, using `.html()` to insert the new fields, you do not have this wrapping `span`... So use `.clone()` instead. It will be easier to target the newly appended markup.

Then, using a variable to count the `click` events... You can create unique `id`.

```
var n=0;
$("body").on('click', '#radioAddQuestion', function () {

  // Counter.
  n++;

  var singleQuestionModule = "singleQuestionModule";

  var question = $(".module:first").clone();
  var question_label = $(".question-label:first").html();

  $(question_label).insertBefore(".options-label");
  console.log(question_label);  // Undefined in this example...

  $(question).insertBefore(".options-label");
  console.log(question.html());

  // Add "_" and a number to the ids.
  $(document).find(".module:last").find("input[type='radio']").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("id",$(this).attr("id")+"_"+n);
  });
});
```

Your [updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/ng11rfr4/11/).